# can not send variable from LoginController by Compact method to Blade file to show the variable values- show me (undefined variable)

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

i have problem in trying to pass variable from method made it in the loginController to pass it to blade file  - when press login button to see the id  of the login user  to try to open restricted area for  him as user while no other person can see the page or the area for  other user

try to send the variable `$userDataa` from LoginController from login method by compact hellper method to the balde file `Home.blade.php` but show me when make login that undefined variable `$userDataa` that try to echo it at blade file `{{$userDataa}}`

//loginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use App\Models\User;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);
        if(auth()->attempt(array('email'=>$input['email'],'password'=>$input['password'])))
        {
            if(auth()->user()->is_admin==1)
            {
                $id =auth()->user()->id;
                $userDataa=User::find($id);
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');

                

            }else{

                $id =auth()->user()->id;
               $userDataa=User::find($id);
               return view ('home',compact('userDataa'));

               //return redirect()->route('home');

            }


        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error','يجب إدخال كل الحقول بشكل صحيح');
        }
    }
}
```

//homeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function adminhome()
    {
        
        return view('adminhome');
    }
}
```

//theBlade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if (session('error'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {{ session('error') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                   <h3>Welcome  in your Area </h3>
{{$userDataa->name}}

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

//route file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/admin/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'adminhome'])->name('admin.home')->middleware('is_admin');
```

//model file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'is_admin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

Comment: In the loginController, you are passing the variable, in the HomeController you are not passing the variable. So the error will pop up when you go to the view using the HomeController.

Comment: auth()->user() is the User model, so you don't need to reload it

Comment: @Ger B - is not correct to call the blade from login contrroler and pass the variable from it ? as i need after login quickly show blade for the loged user only

Comment: You can call the blade file from the LoginController and pass the variable, but you need to pass the variable in every controller that returns the blade file. As commented, for the logged in user, there is no need to pass the variable. It is available in every file using `Auth::user()` (facade) or `auth()->user()`  (helper).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `Auth` facade or `auth` helper? like this

`Auth::user()->name` or `auth()->user()->name`. You don't have to pass it to blade file manually after authenticating the user.

Comment: i try to show the blade for every user make login by his information only so try to send the variable from login controller to the blade by his info and i will apply in the fusture information from tables to show after login for every login user alone - is your solve make what  i want?  or i'am  wrong?  as i  am new in laravel

Comment: when a user log in it's data is available. You can just consume it everywhere.